How to display value of an Oid in C++
How do I display the value of a PostgreSQL Oid ?
I have obtained a vector of Oids from a PostgreSQL Result Set rs
std::vector<Oid> oid_vec = rs.oids();

I want to iterate through the elements of the vector and print out the value of the Oid.
The following does not work, it gives the error "no operator "<<" matches these operands:
for (auto oid : oid_vec) {
    std::cout << "Oid value :" << oid << std::endl; 
}

The following also doesn't work. It gives me the error "this range-based 'for' statement requires a suitable "begin" function and none was found.:
for (auto oid : oid_vec) {
    for (int i : oid) {
        std::cout << "Oid value :" << oid << std::endl; 
    }
}

Is there some oid.getName() or oid.getValue() function I am unaware of to make things easier ?

Show the definition of Oid and a [mcve]. We can't search the documentation for you. Having the definition in the post will allow user to not search for the documentation etc and make the question complete. The error suggest Oid has not overloaded the said operators and has no begin etc.

According to the PostgreSQL documentation, the "The oid type is currently implemented as an unsigned four-byte integer".

... and it's defined here: https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/d35e29387870fecfdb52ffd4c93c651f0c7c1b43/src/include/postgres_ext.h#L31

Then the error "no operator "<<" matches these operands: is odd.

Show the complete and verbatim error message.

Yes, please show the complete error message for the first example. The second example has no chance of working.

There are two error messages: 'E0349: no operator "<<" matches these operands' and 'C2678: binary '<<': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::ostream' (or there is no acceptable conversion).

I have found the solution, I will add it below with formatting.

The following works:
for (auto oid : oid_vec) {
    std::cout << "Oid value :" << uint32_t(oid) << std::endl; 
}

The oid value is now printed out correctly.

Also add some more details into your question as already asked in the comments. And then add also add explanation of what the problem was and how exactly does this answer solve that problem.
